# NoClassDefFoundError in referencing Java Application project from Java Servlet Project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a java application 'JA' and a Java project containing a servlet project 'JS'. From JS I need to use classes present in JA. So, I referenced JA in JS by 
right click project -> deployment assembly -> add -> project 
and have referenced JA.

Now I am able to import the class files in the JS. But when i am trying to instantiate JA in JS then it is showing NoClassDefFoundError for every class in .jar files used in JA. This error is getting removed by adding the .jar files in JS.

My question is, do we need to add all the .jar files in JS, or are there other methods. Am I missing the method of referencing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the exported libs from JA project.

This can be done by **right click on JA project** -> **Java Build Path**, select tab **Order and Export**. On this tab you will see all libraries you have referenced on JA. Select the ones you want to export together with JA, click Ok and this is it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i generally do it. right click JS project -> Java Build Path -> Project  Now add your JA project as dependent project.Deployment assembly just tells you the directory where the project components will be deployed .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently!
I have a maven, jsp & servlets project, i wanted to call a class from another project, it worked (I could browse the methods inside it) but when i ran the servlet i had an error (NoClassDefFoundError)
Add the project in the java build path (both tabs : project & order and export) and add it in the deployment assembly